# React-native: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: react-native

[This Is the Error I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyhSZ.png)I have seen similar questions asked but I can't seem to identify the problem. I am using react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.58.0-rc.2  I have Just Started to learn React-Native. So, My code is very Basic

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class GroupPin extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Hello World !!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});

export default GroupPin;
```

Here's my App.Js File

```js
import React from 'react';
import Component from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Platform, Image, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import GroupPin from './Screens/GroupPin';

export default class App extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    // TODO: You: Do firebase things
    // const { user } = await firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
    // console.warn('User -> ', user.toJSON());

    // await firebase.analytics().logEvent('foo', { bar: '123'});
  }

  render() {
  return <GroupPin />;
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  
});
```

Comment: This bit needs to be destructured: `import Component from 'react';`

Comment: Solved It By Changing  { export default class App extends Component } to  { export default class App extends React. Component } Thank you

Comment: In App.js, join line 1 and line 2 .. `import React , {Component} from 'react';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved It By Changing 
[

> export default class App extends Component

] to

```
export default class App extends React. Component
```